# app.config / program.cs expected by TFS but not in solution explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I added a new project to a solution as a class library. I worked on it for several days and now the time has come to check in my changes to TFS.

However, the following two files are expected by TFS:
`Program.cs` and `app.config`. The check-in fails because they don't exist.

Furthermore, when I go to the solution explorer and try to browse to find the files they aren't there either.

I can check in the project by just excluding them, but I'm afraid this may be breaking something, as well as it's just annoying. (I can't see them to remove them in the solution explorer so they'll show up every time I do a check-in.)

I have edited the `myproject.csproj` file in a text editor and can't find any reference to either file there either.

Comment: There should be no Program.cs and app.config in class library project.

Answer (score 1):

OK I saw that when I tried to check in that project individually it wouldn't give me that option (the rest of the project was already checked in.) It was only when I clicked on the Solution and tried to check in from there that it expected the files, but in the directory of this project.

So I went into the *Source Control Explorer* and browsed to that directory, and sure enough there they were. I was able to delete them from there and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created a console project instead of a class library, suddenly when you want to archive, it also expects a app.config and a class contains the Main() method.
The solution I propose you is to change the output type to calss library.

 [image]

Comment: Strange, it's building with no problems... The output type is a class library already.